# WordPress убрать расстояние после хедера

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Делаю сайт на WordPress + Woocomerce и столкнулся с такой проблемой. На всех страницах отступ после хедера регулируется при помощи Elementor'а и выглядит нормально. Пример ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако на страницах категорий товаров весь блок, а соответственно и отступ, не регулируется  и выглядит слишком большим.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как я могу от него избавиться?

Comment: Например написав пару строк CSS кода, так же в Elementor Pro можно делать шаблоны архивных страниц.